# My Output only prints one Rectangle in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface

```
 public static void createAI()
{        
    AI a = new AI(10,10,15,15); 
    frame.add(a);
    AI b = new AI(100,100,15,15);
    frame.add(b);

}
```

This only shows b; however this prints out a.

```
 public static void createAI()
{        
    AI a = new AI(10,10,15,15); 
    frame.add(a);
}
```

Why cant I do both in one method?
Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Which [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) are you using? Also, what is `AI`?

Comment: Im not sure what layout manager im using. AI is an class that i created. It adds it fine

Answer (score 1):

The default layout manager for a JFrame is the `BorderLayout`. When you use the add(...) method without specifying a constraint, then the component is added to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`. However, only a single component can be added to the CENTER so only the last component added is displayed.

Try something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(a);
panel.add(b);
frame.add(panel);
```

JPanel uses a `FlowLayout` by default so now the components should be displayed horizontally.

If that is not the layout you want then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Alternatively you can just add your component to a different region of the BorderLayout like: `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, a);`
  `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, b);`

Comment: @Eypros, the method signature for the add(...) method is `add(Component, Object)`. Yes I know your method signature does exist, but if you read the API you will see that the method you suggest has been obsolete for over a decade.

Comment: When you say obsolete what do you mean? The original signature for JFrame is `frame.getContentPane().add(region, component);`. You are referring to Frame (AWT)? For JFrame Java 7 refers: _As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary_ which does not make it obsolete.

Comment: @Eypros,  `frame.getContentPane()` returns a `Container object`. You then invoke the `add(...)` method on the `Container` object. You need to look at the `Container.add(...)` method when you read the API. You can also read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and examples on using the BorderLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Probably b is on top of a. Try to invert the sequence of adds, or use the debugger to execute line by line.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work   AI a = new AI(10,10,15,15);         
        AI b = new AI(100,100,15,15);
        frame.add(b);  
        frame.add(a);

Was this what you were suggesting?